# RSPEC test index action with before_action filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, before-filter

I have a `before_action` filter and want to test that the index action is only executed if the user is logged in. Simply put, i don't know how to do this. I'm using my own simple authentication and i know i could use CanCan or similar but for my own learning i'm doing it the hard way!

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
helper_method :logged_in
helper_method :current_user


def current_user

  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:current_user]) if session[:current_user]

end



def logged_in

  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

**ActivitiesController.rb**

```
before_action :logged_in

def index
  @activities = Activity.all.where(user_id: @current_user)
end
```

**Activities_Controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ActivitiesController, :type => :controller do

describe "GET index" do

  before(:each) do
    @activity = FactoryGirl.create(:activity)
    session[:current_user] = @activity.user_id
    @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:current_user]) if session[:current_user]
  end

  it "shows all activities for signed in user" do
    get :index, {user_id: @activity.user_id}
    expect(response).to redirect_to user_activities_path

  end  

end


end
```

**activities.rb(Factory)**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

factory :activity do

association :user

  title { Faker::App.name }
  activity_begin { Faker::Date.forward(10) }
  activity_end { Faker::Date.forward(24) }

end  

end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to user_activities_path
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users/1/activities> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>.
   Expected "http://test.host/users/1/activities" to be === "http://test.host/".
```

Comment: You can test redirection (see [this](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher))

Comment: yea thanks, i've actually changed to a redirect but i'm getting an error. I'll update the question

Comment: of course: you compare `response` with `user_activities_path` (which is a URL or just a string). And be careful you should write `expect(response).to eq(...)` (you missed `eq`)

Comment: i've actually got the following: `expect(response).to redirect_to user_activities_path` and that's what's producing the error

Comment: Your helper `logged_in` uses `@current_user` when I think you would like to use method `current_user` which returns variable `@current_user`. Other words in `logged_in` `@current_user` always is nil (not defined)

Comment: good spot thanks but now i get this error: `Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to user_activities_path
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>`.

Comment: yes, because you create `user` (through factory `activity`) and set `session[:current_user] = @activity.user_id` in spec. And I suggest you to have two spec: positive and negative case.

Comment: not sure why that causes that error?

Comment: It is not error. It is failed test! RSpec reports that expectation is failed. You expect that response should be redirected somewhere (oh I missed you are test that redirection will be on the same page!) but response code is 200 (it is not redirected response code)

Comment: yep, i got that but i don't see why it's not redirecting. As far as i can see, the code is/should be redirecting to the `user_activities_path`

Comment: please approve that all snippets in the question are actual

Comment: yep, they are all actual. Should i be checking for success or that the template is rendered rather than a redirect?

Comment: Well. 1. if it should be redirected it should be redirected to `root_path` (see `logged_in`) not to `user_activities_path`. 2. Why now `logged_in` does not redirect response I can't understand because I think `@current_user` inside `logged_in` method is nil. I see two variants: you have `unless current_user.present?` (which triggers another helper), block `before` in test initialize `@current_user` and this variable is accessible in controller scope (but I think it is wrong because it is absolutely different scopes). I suggest to install gem `pry` and use `binding.pry` method to debug

Comment: So i've changed the `logged in` function to `unless current_user redirect_to root_path`. If the user is not logged in then they should be redirected to the root. I want to test that only logged in users are taken to the `user_activities_path`. I have pry but am still at a loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long discussion I think tests should be smth like this (it is not tested :) )

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ActivitiesController, :type => :controller do

  describe "GET index" do

    before(:each) do
      @activity = FactoryGirl.create(:activity)
    end

    context 'when user is logged' do

      before(:each) do
        session[:current_user] = @activity.user_id
      end

      it "shows all activities for signed in user" do
        get :index, {user_id: @activity.user_id}
        expect(response).to be_success      
      end  
    end

    context 'when user is anonymous' do
      it "redirects user to root path" do
        get :index, {user_id: @activity.user_id}
        expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
      end  
    end

  end


end
```